# cron run-parts exits with exitcode 1 while standalone script runs fine

Tags: cron

After installing `msktutil`, each day cron complains and I receive e mail with text:

```
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/msktutil exited with return code 1
```

when I run:

```
user@box:~$ sudo /etc/cron.daily/msktutil
user@box:~$ echo $?
0
```

Also If I modify msktutil to run in verbose mode, nothing is exposed (it tells me it is to early to change the keytab content).

Which important tests am I missing to pinpoint the (really painful) issue?

/etc/crontab file is:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

and msktutil is a sh script:

```
cat /etc/cron.daily/msktutil
#!/bin/sh

test -x /usr/sbin/msktutil || exit 0

# These options are overridden in /etc/default/msktutil.
# Edit there, not here.
AUTOUPDATE_ENABLED="false"
AUTOUPDATE_OPTIONS=""

[ -r /etc/default/msktutil ] && . /etc/default/msktutil

[ "$AUTOUPDATE_ENABLED" = "true" ] || exit 0
exec /usr/sbin/msktutil --auto-update $AUTOUPDATE_OPTIONS
```

Comment: What is the crontab line?

Comment: Do you run it under root (because you use sudo...)?